# Using sample sizes when combining z-scores

Tags: meta-analysis, weights, z-score

What is the theoretical justification for using the square root of the sample size as the weight when combining z-scores in a meta-analysis?

Is this because the variance of the z-score is proportional to 1/n, where n is the sample size, so the inverse variance is proportional to n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the CLT. Its main issue is convergence in distribution. Rather than writing $Z=\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, we can write $\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. The CLT has some variants, the Lindeberg–Lévy variant  states it in a slightly different manner: $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu)\xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. This means that the difference between the average and the mean converges to the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ **with rate $\sqrt{n}$**.

For our needs, we can re-write the Lindeberg–Lévy variant as $\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. That is, the statistic $\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma}$ converges to the standard normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ **with rate $\sqrt{n}$**.

Why is this important? One can think of the rate of convergence as the speed of approaching $\mu$. Upon combining different variables (which depends on some theory like continuity conditions, [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) and the [LLN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)), we need to make sure they have the same rate of convergence or otherwise the convergence of the sum doesn't hold.
Consider $Z_1=\frac{\bar{X}-\mu_X}{\sigma_X}$ and $Z_2=\frac{\bar{Y}-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}$. If they have the same convergence rate (say $\sqrt{n}$) then we can write something like $\sqrt{n}(Z_1+Z_2)\xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}(0,2)$. If they have different convergence rates, we cannot discuss the convergence of a combination.

This issue of rate of convergence (which in CLT is $\sqrt{n}$) is the reason for writing the square root of the sample size in z-scores. The rate of convergence is an important and nontrivial topic, you can read some more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables).

Comment: What does the letter d means?

Comment: "If they have different convergence rates, we cannot discuss the convergence of a combination." Convergence rate = sqrt(n). Do you mean if there if a different sample size, we cannot discuss the convergence of a combination? But in meta analysis, sample size of individual studies often differs. They will combine by sqrt(n).

Comment: The letter d means convergence in distribution

Comment: different sample sizes don't mean they can't converge. $\sqrt{n_1}$ and $\sqrt{n_2}$ are both rates of $\sqrt{n}$. The problem is, for example, when one converges with rate $\sqrt{n}$ and the other with rate $n$.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the CLT.

Answer (score 0):

Z-scores are estimates scaled by the estimated standard error of those estimates. Say we have two estimates from two samples $$Z_1 = \frac{\bar{X}_1}{\sigma\sqrt{n_1}} = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{n_1}} \sum_{k=1}^{n_1} X_{1k} \\
Z_2 = \frac{\bar{X}_2}{\sigma\sqrt{n_2}} = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{n_2}} \sum_{k=1}^{n_2} X_{2k} $$

where $\sigma$ is the error in the individual observations $X_{ik}$ (which for simplicity we assume as the same in both groups) and $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the sample sizes.

Here you see that if you would simply add $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ together with equal weights then the individual observations $X_{ik}$ do not get equal weights which is less efficient.

$$\sqrt{0.5} Z_1 + \sqrt{0.5} Z_1 = \sum_{i \in [1,2]} \sum_{k=1}^{n_i} \left( \frac{\sqrt{0.5}}{\sigma\sqrt{n_i}} X_{ik} \right)$$

---

The justification is that a weighted mean will have a smaller standard error, in comparison to an unweighted arithmetic mean. (From a different perspective the justification is a larger mean z-score instead of smaller standard error, see at the end)

This relates a bit to [generalized least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares), and [weighted least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares), which have the task to compute an estimate when the observed data points do not have equal variance/error.

What you are doing is computing an average which is a linear estimator and generalized least squares, which will use a weighted mean based on the variance of the individual terms, is the best linear unbiased estimator.

---

Example of a weighted mean having lower variance:

Example: If you have two observations distributed as

$$\bar{x}_1 \sim N(\mu, \sigma_1^2)\\
\bar{x}_2 \sim N(\mu, \sigma_2^2)$$

then the weighted mean (with weights $a_1+a_2=1$) will be distributed as

$$a_1 z_1 +a_2 z_2 \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$$

with the variance a weighted sum $$\sigma^2 = a_1^2 \sigma_1^2 + a_2^2 \sigma_2^2 = \sigma_1^2 -2 a_2 \sigma_1^2 + a_2^2 (\sigma_2^2+\sigma_1^2)$$

which has a minimum in $a_2 = \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}$.

---

Intuitively:

Imagine you have a study with sample size 1000 and a study with sample size 10. The estimate from the latter study has a very large error. When you would average the results of both fifty-fifty then the propagation of error from the inaccurate study will count fifty percent and will lead to a large error in the end result.

The unweighted average of two numbers, one with small error and one with large error, will not have a small error but a medium error. So the average makes the situation worse (because you already had a number with a small error).

---

> Is this because the variance of the z-score is proportional to 1/n, where n is the sample size, so the inverse variance is proportional to n?

The z-scores have variance 1, because they are normalised, but they have different means.

The z-score is roughly distributed as $N(\mu/\sqrt{n},1)$. Where $\mu$ is the population mean. If $\mu$ is non-zero then larger samples will have larger z-scores and that is why you want to give them a stronger weight.

So the comparison with GLS above, which is about different variance instead of different means is a bit twisted, but superficially the principle is related. If you compute the z-scores back to means of the population, then the GLS comparison counts and the goal is to get a linear sum that estimates the population mean and has the lowest variance possible (smaller variance means a larger z-score).

Comment: This has nothing to do with least squares

Comment: @Spätzle this has to do with computing an average which is a linear estimator (and unbiased if the individual z-scores are unbiased) and GLS is the best linear unbiased estimator.

Comment: @Spätzle, OP's question is about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting ... " to minimize the variance of the weighted average."